# Geolocation with typescript

Tags: typescript, geolocation

I have the following code snippet:

```
pos:number;

getPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

        this.pos = position.coords.latitude;
```

when I debug I get undefined on this.pos, and some number on position.coords.latitude

But when I have the following code snippet:

```
pos:any;

getPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {

        this.pos = position.coords.latitude;
```

then the this.pos is set.
Why such a behaviour ?

Comment: Are you sure this behaviour is happening? Type annotations don't exist in the final javascript so they won't have any affect on the behaviour of code. Maybe it's a bug with the debugger... if you do console.log(this.pos); after setting this.pos does it output undefined in the first case still

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure position is defined and you are getting in there then it's because the `this` has changed. The `this` context can change depending on how it's called. If you are calling it through an event then the `this` will be scoped the the window or the element originating the event. Example

```
export class GeoService {
  public pos: any;

  public getPosition() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.pos = position;
    });
  }
}

let geo = new GeoService();

// When called, `this` will be the window
setTimeout(geo.getPosition, 1000);

// When called, `this` will be the dom element
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click', geo.getPosition);
```

You can get around this by using an anonymous function that calls the original objects method-

```
// When called, `this` will be the window
setTimeout(() => { geo.getPosition(); }, 1000);

// When called, `this` will be the dom element
document.getElementById('myDiv').addEventListener('click', () => { geo.getPosition(); });
```

Or, by setting getPosition as a property of the GeoService class using a lambda to ensure it's scoped properly.

```
export class GeoService {
  public pos: any;

  public getPosition = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      this.pos = position;
    });
  }
}
```

Caveats to the latter. It can make things simpler and reduce redundant code but keep in mind that this creates a new function each time the GeoService class is constructed. This means each instance will have a copy of this function, instead of sharing a common memory space. In other words, it's more costly on memory.

Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: This answer was a while ago. Today I'd recommend `geo.getPosition.bind(geo)`